# RxAndroidBle read and then write to a characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-java2, rxandroidble

I am trying to read from a characteristic and then write to the same characteristic, but was unable to figure out how. As a first step, I was trying to do multiple writes following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667549/rxandroidble-multiple-characteristic-notifications-and-read-write):

```
connectionDisposable =
                connectionObservable.flatMap(rxBleConnection -> {
                    return rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(SSID, bytes)
                            .flatMap(ssidBytes -> rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(SSID, bytes)
                                    .flatMap(ssid2Bytes -> rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(SSID, bytes)));
                })
                        .subscribe(ssid3Bytes -> {
                            //do something
                        }, this::onError, this::onComplete);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Single<R> conforms to ObservableSource<? extends R>
```

It would be great if someone can help me figure out how to do more than just one read or one write using RxAndroidBle.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you observe is because the example uses RxJava 1, and the current version of RxAndroidBle is based on RxJava 2. During the transition some APIs changed from `Observable<byte[]>` to `Single<byte[]>`.

Flat mapping `Observable` to `Single` cannot be done with a `.flatMap()` operator but needs a `.flatMapSingle()`.

Apart from that — if you are not interested in what data you had written then a simpler (in my opinion at least) alternative is available:

```java
Completable writeMultipleCharacteristics(RxBleConnection rxBleConnection) {
    return Completable.concatArray(
        rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(SSID, bytes).ignoreElement(),
        rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(SSID, bytes).ignoreElement(),
        rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(SSID, bytes).ignoreElement()
    );
}
```

P.S. I have updated the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667549/rxandroidble-multiple-characteristic-notifications-and-read-write) you mentioned with RxJava 2 code.